# Delete all characters in even-number position

Tags: php, trim, raw-data

If I have this string:

```
k6s6k6s6c1u6t661w651z6k6z6z6k611
```

How can delete all the characters in even-numbers position? (2, 4, 6...)

```
kskscut6w5zkzzk1
```

I tried:

```
$str = "k6s6k6s6c1u6t661w651z6k6z6z6k611";
$arr = str_split($str, 2);
print_r(substr_replace($arr ,"",-1));
```

Its OK. But it doesn't seem to work if I want to continue the script with the trimmed string.

```
Array
(
    [0] => k
    [1] => s
    [2] => k
    [3] => s
    [4] => c
    [5] => u
    [6] => t
    [7] => 6
    [8] => w
    [9] => 5
    [10] => z
    [11] => k
    [12] => z
    [13] => z
    [14] => k
    [15] => 1
)
```

I want raw string. Not arrays.

```
kskscut6w5zkzzk1
```

I could use explode too, but they are not always fixed characters.

This should be simple. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't why everyone keeps asking that.
It's not!

Comment: because not one can think of a real world application for this. So let us know, I'm curious.

Comment: Also curious. What is it for? :)

Comment: @Dagon:: At least I do.
It's a small part of my script.
Give an anwser if you have please. : )

Comment: Quid pro quo, tell me why and i will tell you how.

Comment: @Dagon: Never mind. I got the answer. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `implode`.

```
$str = "k6s6k6s6c1u6t661w651z6k6z6z6k611";
$arr = str_split($str, 2);
$str2 = implode("", substr_replace($arr ,"",-1));
echo $str2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "k6s6k6s6c1u6t661w651z6k6z6z6k611";
$new_str = '';
$str_length =  strlen($str);
for($i=0; $i< $str_length; $i++)
{
    if($i%2==0) $new_str .= $str{$i};
}

echo $new_str;
```

The output: `kskscut6w5zkzzk1`

Comment: Thanks. But Jacob Oettinger looks simpler to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
preg_replace('/(.)(.)/', '$1', $str);
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation as to why you think your code solves the problm.